# How to convert Promise to String? I used Axios and return the data to my react Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, es6-promise

I have an API call to Cloudinary after the image was uploaded it returns a promise instead of a string. I wanted to to get the URL on my uploaded image to be saved on my database.

Here is the return screenshot:

[image: Debug return result]

Here is my Axios code:

```
export const uploadImage = imageUpload => async dispatch => {
  try {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', imageUpload);

    const res = await axios.post(
      'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/frank/image/upload',
      formData
    );

    return res.data.secure_url;
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.error;
  }
};
```

I also tried using `.then()`, but my variable returns `undefined`.

Comment: You have to call the function with await

Comment: Where and how are you using that function? if it returns a promise then use await before the promise. You are already inside an async function so that should work.

Comment: Can you just log the `res.data` and be sure that it has `secure_url`?

Comment: What is `dispatch` and why do you have it there? `uploadImage` returns a function that returns a promise that accepts a `displatch` argument which you never use. Does this has anything to do with your `redux` state management? You should get rid of `dispatch` and make it like this `export const uploadImage = async imageUpload => {...}`.

Comment: This looks like an async action creator for `redux-thunk`. Probably this is why there is a `dispatch`.

Comment: Okay, so I dispatch the payload and is already on my state if I call the function. Now my problem is I can't setState my data. Since initially it is empty and will only map to state if I dispatch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I dispatch my res through my redux thunk

```
dispatch({
  type: UPLOAD_SUCCESS,
  payload: res.data.secure_url
});
```

Then on my Component I used useEffect hook to set my formData. I also used useState hook for my props

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({photo: '', imgURL: ''});
```

If the the dispatch is triggered

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFormData({ ...formData, photo: image });
}, [image]);
```

Now my photo is set to a String. Thanks for sharing you ideas. It helped.